# Sort list of long dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of two dictionaries in Python

```
list = [{'id' : 'ewsfsdf', 
           '_source' : 
                      {'timestamp':'2018-08-08T20:56:01', 
                       'bytes':'43534534'}},
         {'id' : 'ewsfsdz', 
           '_source' : 
                      {'timestamp':'2018-08-08T20:57:01', 
                       'bytes':'4354343534'}}]
```

I would like to sort the list element by the timestamp in the 2nd depth dictionary.
I looked up many other examples of python but could not find a suitable solution to order list element by a dictionary element of a dictionary element in a list.

Can you give me a clue?

Comment: You should try to not use `list` as a variable name, as it is one of the built-in functions.

Comment: @James Very true, although `list` isn't actually a function, it's a type (aka class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dateutil` package to parse datetime and sort it based on that. You can install `dateutil` package by doing `pip install python-dateutil`

```
from dateutil import parser
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: parser.parse(x['_source']["timestamp"]))
# [{'id': 'ewsfsdf', '_source': {'timestamp': '2018-08-08T20:56:01', 'bytes': '43534534'}}, {'id': 'ewsfsdz', '_source': {'timestamp': '2018-08-08T20:57:01', 'bytes': '4354343534'}}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime
l = [{'id' : 'ewsfsdf', 
           '_source' : 
                      {'timestamp':'2018-08-08T20:56:01', 
                       'bytes':'43534534'}},
         {'id' : 'ewsfsdz', 
           '_source' : 
                      {'timestamp':'2018-08-08T20:57:01', 
                       'bytes':'4354343534'}}]

print( sorted(l, key=lambda k: datetime.datetime.strptime(k['_source']["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) )
```

*or*

```
print(sorted(l, key=lambda k: k['_source']['timestamp']))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 'ewsfsdf', '_source': {'timestamp': '2018-08-08T20:56:01', 'bytes': '43534534'}}, {'id': 'ewsfsdz', '_source': {'timestamp': '2018-08-08T20:57:01', 'bytes': '4354343534'}}]
```

- You can use `lambda` in `key`
- Use `datetime.datetime.strptime(k['_source']["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` to convert string to datetime object

Comment: This is a good solution, but it might be cleaner to factor the lambda out into a named function

Comment: Do we need to convert a generic ISO timestamp to a datetime object? String ordering is enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
print(sorted(list, key=lambda d: d['_source']['timestamp']))
```

Depending on how you want to sort by timestamp, you may need to parse the timestamp to another format that's comparable time-wise and not just lexicographical order.

Comment: Simple string comparison is sufficient on the ISO 8601 timestamps in the OP's data, no conversion is necessary, assuming that they all use the same representation.

Comment: @PM2Ring That is a good observation

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `list` method `sort` and `dparser`

```
from dateutil.parser import dparser
l.sort(key=lambda x: dparser.parse(x['_source']['timestamp']))
```

Notice that this will return nothing and sort your list inplace

Comment: alternatively `arrow.Arrow`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to sort the timestamp (from earliest to latest or latest to earliest) but here's how you could get into the second depth:

```
list[0]['_source']['timestamp']
```

If you want to cycle through the whole list, simply get the length of the list and cycle through a for loop (make sure not to overflow the list by going out of range with the index).

I hope this helps!